# Sqlite : ORDER BY the MAX value of each group, but returning all rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm stuck with this one.
I would like to order a table by the max value of each group. (but returning all rows).

As it is always easier with an example :

```
Team | Player | Score
---
red  | Bob  | 32  
red  | Jill | 34  
red  | Shawn| 42  
blue | Jake | 29  
blue | Paul | 26
blue | Mike | 35
```

The desired result set :

```
blue | Jake | 35  
blue | Paul | 35
blue | Mike | 35
red  | Bob  | 42   
red  | Jill | 42   
red  | Shawn| 42
```

Comment: So show us the query you are currently trying to get working

Comment: Is this MYSQL or SQLite?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.team, t.player,
       (select max(t2.score) from t t2 where t2.team = t.team) as max_score
from t;
```

You can do something similar with a `group by` and `join`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use  a inner join on select table

```
  select t.team, a.player, t.score
  from my_table 
  inner join (
      select team, max(score)
      from my_table 
      group by team
  ) t on t.team = a.team 
  order by t.team
```

Comment: @SloanThrasher  .I'm ..looking to the expected  result  .. and i need  the player name too  .. not only team and max  ...